# Does $f \leq f \circ f^\dagger \circ f$ hold in an arbitrary allegory?

Tags: category-theory, relations, examples-counterexamples

If $f$ is an arrow of $\mathrm{Rel}$, then $f \leq f \circ f^\dagger \circ f.$

*Proof.* Suppose $xy \in f$. Then $xy \in f, yx \in f^\dagger, xy \in f$. Thus $xy \in f \circ f^\dagger \circ f.$

**Question.** Does this inequality hold in an arbitrary [allegory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_%28category_theory%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apply the *modularity law*

> $\,uv\,\land w\ \le\ (u\land\, wv^\dagger)v\,$

with $v,w=f:A\to B$ and $u:=1_A$. We get
$$f\ =\ 1_Af\land f\ \le\  (1_A\land ff^\dagger)f\ \le\ (ff^\dagger)f\,.$$